# Path from root on my server without using domain name

Tags: php, html

Currently, I'm referencing images, stylesheets etc. like this on my home server:

```
http://localhost/igniter/assets/images/
```

However, this requires `allow_url_include` to be set to `On` in my php.ini file. I read that, as far as possible, `allow_url_include` should be set to `Off`.

To do that, I'd need to alter my images path to something like:

```
wwwroot/igniter/assets/images/
```

Basically, how can I reference the root of my hosting account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allow_url_include` is about being able to pass URLs as filenames to `include`, `require`, and their brothers. It has nothing to do with referencing things from the HTML. To illustrate, this is a piece of code that will behave differently based on this settings:

```
<?php
include 'http://www.example.org/constants.php';

echo SOME_CONSTANT_DEFINED_IN_CONSTANTS_PHP;
```

If you allow URL includes, it will make a HTTP request to www.example.org, download the output of constants.php, and include that as PHP source; if you disallow URL includes, it will fail to include anything (and react according to your `error_reporting` setting).

Referring stylesheets, images, etc. on the client (that is, from the HTML you output), such as in this example:

```
<?php
do_some_stuff();
?>
<img src="http://www.example.org/images/img000.jpg" />
```

will work fine either way.

Note that scripts are subject to the Same Origin Policy implemented in modern browsers, but that's a different story altogether.

Comment: I have my header, footer etc stored in header.php, footer.php etc which are then included as and when needed. Is it really that bad to have `allow_url_include` set to On?

Comment: Yes, it's bad, and it's unnecessary. Think about the difference between a URL and a local file path for a while, and I hope you'll see why.